# ¿Como ocultar ventana emergente de usuarios ya registrados al momento de copiar una contraseña?

Tags: javascript, html5

es que tengo una ventana que le permite al usurio cambiar la contraseña y para esto el usuario tiene que ingresar primero su contraseña para poder ser modificada, pero el problema es que cuando el usuario le da click en el campo para ingresar su contraseña google le saca el cuadrito de contraseñas guardadas y yo no quiero que pase eso si no que el usuario la ingrese. ¿Es solucionable?

Comment: No se entiende nada, por favor, haz la explicación de una forma simple y usa signos de puntuaciñon.

Comment: Me agrego a lo que dice @JDev, te sugiero dar un [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour), por el sitio para que sepas como preguntar y reformules tu pregunta.

Comment: Con *google le saca el cuadrito de contraseñas guardadas* te refieres al navegador Chrome y su funcionalidad de guardar contraseñas?

Comment: Si a eso me refiero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar el atributo `autocomplete` que se encuentra disponible para aquellos `<input>` que reciben un número o un texto como parámetro de entrada. Poniéndole al atributo el valor `new-password` conseguirías que el navegador no trate de buscar dentro de las contraseñas guardadas de Google Chrome.

> **"new-password"**
>
> A new password. When creating a new account or changing passwords, this is the "Enter your new password" field, as
>   opposed to any "Enter your current password" field that might be
>   present. This may be used by the browser both to avoid accidentally
>   filling in an existing password and to offer assistance in creating a
>   secure password.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<input type="password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

**Referencia:** [Atributo autocomplete HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos/autocomplete)